# Two Way Databinding For Spinner Selected Item

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner, android-databinding

I have a view Model which has a field `district` which is the type of `MutableLiveData<String>` I have initialized it with `var district = MutableLiveData<String>("")` I want to bind the selected item to it for that i have a BindingClass

```
object SpinnerBindingUtil {
        @BindingAdapter(value = ["selectedValue", "selectedValueAttrChanged"], requireAll = false)
        fun bindSpinnerData(
        pAppCompatSpinner: Spinner,
        newSelectedValue: String,
        newTextAttrChanged: InverseBindingListener
        ) {
    pAppCompatSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(
            parent: AdapterView<*>?,
            view: View,
            position: Int,
            id: Long
        ) {
            newTextAttrChanged.onChange()
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
    }
    if (newSelectedValue != null) {
        val pos =
            (pAppCompatSpinner.adapter as ArrayAdapter<String?>).getPosition(
                newSelectedValue
            )
        pAppCompatSpinner.setSelection(pos, true)
    }
}

@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "selectedValue", event = "selectedValueAttrChanged")
fun captureSelectedValue(pAppCompatSpinner: AppCompatSpinner): String {
    return pAppCompatSpinner.selectedItem as String
}
```

}

and here is my xml

```
                    <Spinner
                    selectedValue="@= 
                    {addConsumerViewModel.district}"
                    android:entries="@array/districts"
                    android:id="@+id/districtSpinner"
                    style="@style/AddConsumerSpinner"/>
```

but i am getting error how can i solve this

Comment: Please share picture of error as well

Comment: What kind of error do you face and where is the `Spinner`? I see `Button` instead

Comment: ```Cannot find a getter for <android.widget.Spinner selectedValue> that accepts parameter type 'java.lang.String'
 ``` This is the error i am getting

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman spinner

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman here I am using MutableLiveData<String>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *kotlin* you have to use `kapt` to working with data binding properly. In your module level `build.gradle` apply this plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

After that you probably face *error:  expected* type issues. Then make your binding adapter like simple *`kt`* file by removing `object SpinnerBindingUtil {}`:

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["selectedValue", "selectedValueAttrChanged"], requireAll = false)
fun bindSpinnerData(
    pAppCompatSpinner: Spinner,
    newSelectedValue: String,
    newTextAttrChanged: InverseBindingListener
) {
    pAppCompatSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(
            parent: AdapterView<*>?,
            view: View,
            position: Int,
            id: Long
        ) {
            newTextAttrChanged.onChange()
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
    }
    if (newSelectedValue != null) {
        val pos =
            (pAppCompatSpinner.adapter as ArrayAdapter<String?>).getPosition(
                newSelectedValue
            )
        pAppCompatSpinner.setSelection(pos, true)
    }
}

@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "selectedValue", event = "selectedValueAttrChanged")
fun captureSelectedValue(pAppCompatSpinner: AppCompatSpinner): String {
    return pAppCompatSpinner.selectedItem as String
}
```

Comment: sorry thats a mistake i have updated it with custom attribute ```selectedValue```

Comment: getting error ```Could not find accessor java.lang.String.value```

Comment: @AseemSalim, Have you checked that?